# What are the advantages of flanking an enemy?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

What bonuses do I get when I flank an enemy? What bonuses does the enemy get when he flanks me? Are they the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flanking *negates* cover, including "full cover", so it will confer a 20% (partial) or 40% (full) difference in hit chance when there is cover.  It confers a higher critical chance - 50% base chance, regardless of whether there is cover or not.  It applies both ways (you flanking bad guys, bad guys flanking you).

Comment: That applies to both the player and the enemy (per question)?

Comment: @james Jiao whoops, forgot to comment on that.  Updated.

Comment: When you flank an enemy with soldier A, does your soldier B also receive a bonus even though they are not personally flanking? I ask because I believe high ground works this way?

Comment: @Andrew Moylan High Ground just provides a bonus to hit.  Flanking is relative for each potential shooter.  See here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87557/how-do-you-flank-an-enemy