# Three musketeers flanking achievement - Civ5

Tags: achievements, civilization-5

Playing as Napoleon/French in Civ5, I am struggling to get the "Three Musketeers" achievement. I suspect the answer is somewhere in what is considered to be "flanking" ([How do you flank an enemy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87557/how-do-you-flank-an-enemy)), but not quite sure. Has anyone achieved this, and know how to get it?

Comment: That linked question is for XCOM: Enemy Unknown, just so you're aware :)  Civ5 is a very different game.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry - I meant to include in my question that the reference was not Civ5 specific - as I couldn't find flanking in terms of Civ5 directly, but I figured flanking will mean the same in any game (just done differently depending on the game).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky one, mostly because it's got some very specific conditions you're unlikely to encounter in normal play.

First, you're going to need *at least* 3 Musketeer units.  Advancing the start age so that you don't have to grind through a bunch of low-level techs to get to the gunpowder age speeds this up.  Play on an easy difficulty level so that producing the units is fast.  Having more than three is better - if you can completely surround the unit with Musketeers, you'll have a much easier time of it.

Second, you need a unit that you can trap and then kill.  City States will have units wandering around that you can surround, or you can play on a mountainous map with another civ.  I don't believe this one is doable in a hotseat game between two players, sadly.

Third, you've got to flank the enemy unit with your Musketeers.  Contrary to my previous belief, this just means having several units in hexes adjacent to the same enemy unit.

Finally, you've got to kill it with your attack.  I'd suggest saving first, and then weakening the unit if the odds aren't overwhelming that you'll kill with one hit.  Policies in the "Honor" track can be helpful here, as they'll impart combat bonuses you might find beneficial.

Comment: The paragraph about unit facing is incorrect. Unit facing in Civ V is purely cosmetic.

Comment: agent86, thanks for the answer. It generally makes sense. Silly me always started in ancient era. I will accept that answer for only that one point... LOL! @Studoku, thanks for the comment - do you ahve any reference for unit facing being only cosmetic? I would rather edit than -1 the whole answer though.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh I've been playing since Civ V came out and never seen a bonus due to facing. There's also the fact that facing doesn't even display in strategic view.

Comment: @Studoku, I guess I made this too hard on myself - I tried to reproduce my understanding of flanking in a hotseat game just now and was unsuccessful.  Answer edited.  My bad!

Comment: Finally got the achievement. Studoku, you may be correct about facing, but I can not say for sure, as my units were all facing the same direction anyways. The important thing was positioning of my Musketeers. I was on the border of Persia, with my three Musketeers standing in the shape of a closing round bracket, on the edge of Persia's border. Darius came to me with a Pikeman to the edge, right in the position where I wanted him, and then I attacked with the top-most Musketeer, then the second (middle) Musketeer killed the Pikeman, and I got the achievement. Very simple in the end, then!

Answer (score 13):

A flanking bonus in Civ V is given when you attack an enemy unit while one of your other units is adjacent to it. This represents the tactical value of surrounding the enemy.

To do this achievement, you need to be playing as France and to have three musketeer units. Naming them is optional but for this example we'll call them Porthos, Athos and Aramis. You'll also need an enemy unit- city states tend to have some around. Using a city state for this also means you don't need to declare war until you're in position.

Your victim needs to be a military unit and should be weak enough that your musketeers can kill it. Most pre-gunpowder units will do. Better still, bring ranged units along to weaken the enemy.

Use the ranged units to weaken the enemy, then move Athos and Aramis next to it. Finally, have Porthos attack and kill it. He should get a bonus from the musketeers and you should get the achievement.

Comment: A very good answer, Studoku. Thanks! I love the reference to Aramis, Athos and Porthos. LOL.